# Trying to read a List of int array from yml file and load with spring annotation @Value List<int[]>

Tags: java, arrays, spring-boot, annotations

I am trying injecting properties from .yml file into fields annotated with @Value.

```
        @Value("#{'${dataconfig.range-List}'.split(',')}")
private List<int[]> rangeList;
```

**App.yml file**

```
    range-List: [ [ 160,30,30 ],
                 [ 311,60,60 ],
                 [ 361,480,360 ] ]
```

I have tried following but nothing worked

```
@Value("#{'${dataConfig.range-List}'.split(',')}")
private List<int[]> rangeList;

@Value("#{'${dataConfig.range-List:range-List}'}")
private List<int[]> rangeList;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this directly, but you can take an alternative route like this:

1 - Update your `.yml` file as follows:

```
custom:
  rangeList[0]: "[160,30,30]"
  rangeList[1]: "[311,60,60]"
  rangeList[2]: "[361,480,360]"
```

2 - Add a `ConfigurationProperties` to read the range list settings. *(You can write shorter code to convert.)*

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "custom")
public class CustomConfigurationProperties {

    private List<String> rangeList;
    private List<int[]> rangeListWithArray = new ArrayList<>();

    public CustomConfigurationProperties(List<String> rangeList) {
        this.rangeList = rangeList;
    }

    public List<String> getRangeList() {
        return rangeList;
    }

    public void setRangeList(List<String> rangeList) {
        this.rangeList = rangeList;
        this.converter();
    }

    private void converter() {
        for (String range : this.rangeList) {
            String[] values = range
                    .replaceAll("\\[", "")
                    .replaceAll("\\]", "")
                    .replaceAll("\\s", "")
                    .split(",");
            int[] result = new int[values.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                try {
                    result[i] = Integer.parseInt(values[i]);
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {}
            }
            this.rangeListWithArray.add(result);
        }
    }
}
```

3 - You can now use it wherever you want by injecting `CustomConfigurationProperties`.

[If you click here](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot), you will explore the **@ConfigurationProperties** description in more detail.